# Bank statement for Visa

Tags: visas, japan, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have got my bank statement printed on Saturday and i will be going to submit my visa application for Japan on Thursday. 
So there is a gap of 4 days in between, is that a concern and should i get latest statement again just before visa application submission?

Comment: The requirements usually are about "recent", not "fresh". IMHO "end of last month" is always a good way to find which one (and at beginning of month like now, it could be also the previous months). Often longer period are preferred than really fresh (to discover money parking)

Comment: Not enough for an answer but if IIRC mine was almost a month old when I submitted an application, it turned out fine.

Answer (score 3):

No you should be fine. As stated earlier, the statements should be 'recent' and there's no requirement for them to be printed on the day of the visa appointment.

On a side note, aren't statements generated monthly? If so, you would anyway be printing for the close of the most recent month, unless by 'printing statements' you mean you are printing transaction history directly from the account.

Comment: Thanks Bhushan. Generally monthly statement are sent to customers regularly but Statement can be taken anyday from bank where they will print and stamp it.

Comment: Sweet. That explains it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to show the latest bank statement but there no hard and fast rule about how much "lastest" is considered "latest". But 4 days is not a long time and you should be fine. Even my bank statements were 1 week old at the time of application.